# Windows Phone - Hyperlinks Requiring Long Press

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, hyperlink, windows-phone

So I've run in to an issue when testing a site on a Nokia Lumia 920, that only seems to be occurring on this site.

Basically, when pressing any hyperlink, nothing happens apart from the hover effect being applied very, very briefly, and the grey opacity background appearing. To get the link to actually be clicked I'm having to hold my finger down for a short amount of time, but not quite long enough that the context menu opens.

Is there anything I can do to work out what is causing this or any fixes I can try?

I have tried the following on the body but that doesnt' seem to have helped any:

```
-ms-touch-action: manipulation; /* IE10  */
touch-action: manipulation;     /* IE11+ */
```

Thanks